# Adding constraints in Q-learning and assigning rewards if constraints are violated

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, dynamic-programming, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I took an RL course recently and I am writing a Q-learning controller for a power management application where I have continuous states and discrete actions. I am using a neural network (Q-network) for approximation the action values and selecting the maximum action value. Like any control system, I have certain constraints or bounds over variables that cannot be violated by the agent. Say, if my controller's (agent) actions are to discharge or charge a battery, the resultant energy cannot be less than 0 or more than the maximum capacity respectively.

I want to understand how do add such constraints in the action selection or value approximation routine? Two approaches come to mind

(1) Say I am running one episode for T steps. At every step, I input my current state to the Q-network and select the maximum action value. Upon taking this action, if my constraints are violated I can assign a huge negative reward, if not I can assign the associated reward. Eventually all the actions that get huge negative rewards (corresponding to undesirable behaviour), will be avoided thus the agent will operate within the model constraints. However, if I think from an optimazation point of view, such actions should NEVER be taken since they don't fall in the allowed region. So ideally, I should stop the iterations right there because there is all sequential actions will be unacceptable. This will cause a severe waste of data.

(2) Second, I feed my current state to the Q-network, select the action corresponding to max Q-value and check the constraint. IF violated, I go take the action corresponding to the second highest Q-value and repeat until my constraint(s) is satisfied. But will this ever lead to optimality?

I posit this might be a recurring problem while training autonomous control systems that involve constraints over multiple variables. Will be really glad to get your feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that option (1) is more advisable and what is typically done. If you really don't want to execute an action, just don't and stop the episode (and give a huge negative reward). Regarding option (2), I don't think it will lead to optimality.

Also, Q-learning is an off-policy algorithm. This means you can train your *target policy* by using samples collected by some other *samplers policies*, which can be "safer" and avoid dangerous actions. This, however, might take more time due to the reduced exploration.

That's anyway a very common problem in RL. I suggest you to look at "cost sensitive exploration" on Google, you will find some interesting studies about your problem.

**REPLY TO COMMENTS**

I don't fully get it. Do you already have a dataset of tuple `(s,a,r,s')`? (collected by whatever agent / policy). If so, don't stop the episode and just learn (using a batch algorithm, like fitted Q-iteration). I suggested you to stop if you have to collect data online: you collect one action, update the policy by the Q-learning update rule, then continue the episode. If that's the case, and safety is your primary concern, just stop the episode whenever something not allowed is going to happen.

The only problem I see related to "it will take to much to learn" arises if your true goal is "far in time" (eg, you give a positive reward after some time) and it will be hard for the agent to experience it. That's however unvoidable: there is always a compromise between "safety / learning time" and between "exploration / exploitation".

Comment: Thanks @Simon. What I cannot understand is that if I end the episode when agent takes an action that leads to violating one of the constraints, I'm wasting the corresponding data. Say I am learning over 24 hours and my agent takes action at each time-step of 1 hour. My State is defined as, S = {v1, v2, v3}. I have historical time-series data for v1 and v2 for 365 days. At t=1, each day, I assign a fixed value to V3 and let the agent explore. Now my agent takes an invalid action at t=2, assign a huge negative R and stop the training. Haven't I wasted training data for this day?

Comment: I'm guessing since RL agents need a lot of time to train, I will have to give it large training data. My question is, can I just copy this data for 365 days and extend it to say 2 years, 3 years etc? How will this affect the performance of my agent? How are such problems tackled in RL?

Comment: @wannabe_nerd I edited my reply (not enough chars allowed in a comment). I also forgot to mention that Q-learning is offline, so you can use data collected by another (safer) policy.

Comment: @Simon there is a another question [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/how-to-handle-invalid-moves-in-reinforcement-learning)..they say to ignore the invaild action, little confused about it, whats your thought on that?  Thank you

Comment: @Naveen I still think that giving negative reward for violating the action is the most principled way. Selecting only acceptable moves means that the actions set is different at each time step, and I am not sure if there is any guarantee of convergence in that case. On the contrary, penalizing invalid action means that you just hand-tune the reward and the transition function, which is legit. Maybe in practice selecting only valid actions could work better (I don't know), but in most papers (like Deepmind ones) they usually constrain the action (sometimes even without any penalty).

Comment: @Simon Thanks :) "but they constrain without any penalty" does this mean ignoring, setting their values to zero?

Comment: @Naveen It means that they just clip the action. Let's say the max action is 10. The policy says to execute 15. You can clip it to 10 and penalize for the additional 5, or you can just clip it to 10 ignoring any penalty.

Comment: @Naveen You are welcome :) Btw, this is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046656/why-should-continuous-actions-be-clamped